# Trying to do simple thing in AngularJS: form->if you put right word->button appears->u can click and go to a different page;

Tags: angularjs

Trying to do simple thing in AngularJS: form->if you put right word->button appears->u can click and go to a different page;(i didn;t try to put a link to the button since it doesn;t appear even without a link)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="MyCtrl.pass">
        <div class="button" ng-show="kPass">click me</div>
    </div>


<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.kPass = false;
    $scope.pass = "empty";
    $scope.$watch($scope.pass,function(){
        if($scope.pass == "parola"){
            $scope.kPass = !$scope.kPass;
        }
    })
};
```

problem: if i type in parola, the button does not appear
i am new to java script. thanks !

Comment: Try `$scope.kPass = !$scope.kPass;` JavaScript is case-sensitive. And you define the variable as `$scope.kPass = false;`, not `$scope.Kpass`.

Answer (score 2):

You should first read some angular tutorials, you have totaly wrong access to scope and you are using wrong $watch

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.kPass = false;
    $scope.pass = "empty";
    $scope.$watch('pass',function(){
        if($scope.pass == "parola"){
            $scope.kPass = !$scope.Kpass;
        }
    })
};

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="pass">
        <div class="button" ng-show="kPass">click me</div>
    </div>


<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And next thing, you are overkilling your code. You can inline it in template without any controller function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div >
        <input type="text" ng-model="pass">
        <div class="button" ng-show="pass == 'parola' ">click me</div>
    </div>


<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also i have another quick question: if i do     <div class="button" ng-show="pass == 'parola' " href="secondpage.html">click me</div>   why doesn;t it work; if i click the button it won't get me to another page

Comment: no problem :) Angular takes some time to understand , but then it is beast :) (It is still beast when you dont understand

Comment: did you saw button with href ? :) <a class="button" ng-show="pass == 'parola'" href="secondpage.html">Click me</a>

Comment: @MilosMosovsky buttons don't have href. Links do.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors here.

First, the password field is bound to `MyCtrl.pass`. But you're watching the value of $scope.pass

Second, $scope.$watch expects an angular expression to evaluate as argument, not a value to watch. So watching the string `'MyCtrl.pass'` would be the correct thing to do.

Third, you shouldn't use a watch at all. You should just use `ng-show="isPasswordValid(pass)"`(see below), and return true or false from this function.

Fourth, instead of doing `$scope.kPass = ($scope.pass == "parola")`, you're inverting the value of `$scope.kPass`, but only if the value is correct. So if it goes from incorrect to correct, `kPass` will become true. Then if it becomes incorrect, `kPass` will stay true. And if it becomes correct again, it will become false.

So, to resume, all you need is

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="pass">
    <div class="button" ng-show="isPasswordValid(pass)">click me</div>
</div>
```

and

```
$scope.isPasswordValid = function(password) {
    return pass === 'parola';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app',[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  Please input : 'parola' <input type="text" ng-model="pass">
  <button ng-show="pass == 'parola'">Next step</button>
  </body>
```